# On FreeBSD what tool is used to dislay the DNSSEC signature expiry date for a zone?

Tags: bind, freebsd, dnssec

We use FreeBSD-12 and Bind-9.11.6.  We have DNSSEC enabled for some of our domains.  I wish to verify the signature expiry date for these zones.  I cannot seem to locate any information on exactly how this is done. Can someone provide me with this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`drill -D [domain]` should return the RRSIG value for your domain (if DNSSEC is working) with the expiration as well

Comment: Sorry it's `drill -D [domain]` to enable DNSSEC, you can find more information about drill [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/drill) I'll edit my answer

Comment: This is what I had returned:

`172800 IN RRSIG A 8 3 172800 20190505052042 20190405052042 59931`

I gather the key signing date was  2019-04-05 at 05:20:42 and that the key expires on 2019-05-05 05:20:42.  Am I correct?

Comment: Pretty much. According to the [RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4034.txt), 2019-04-05 is the signature inception date, as in the date/time that the key is valid from and you are correct that 2019-05-05 is the expiration date.